# How to handle Closures with asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm trying to do some asynchronous messaging for a controller project that I'm doing, and the goal of the following function is to return a callback to an appjar `app.registerEvent` call, which will update the status section of the motor control UI.

```
def motorStatusMonitor(loop: aio.AbstractEventLoop, app: aj.appjar.gui, Messenger: cmd.PyCmdMessenger.CmdMessenger)-> Callable:
    async def getStatus(aFuture):
        nonlocal Messenger
        nonlocal app
        # Ask for the current status of the motor
        t = await Control.sendCommand(Messenger, "Status")
        d = {t[1][0]: t[1][1], t[1][2]: t[1][3]}  # parse the response
        def statusChanger():  # need a closure to write to the app when called
            nonlocal d  # use the message from above
            nonlocal app  # use the app passed with motorStatusMonitor
            app.openTab("Main", "Control")
            app.openLabelFrame("Status")
            app.setLabel("motorStatus", f"Motor A: \t\t {get('A', d, '???')}\nMotor B: \t\t {get('B', d, '???')}") # Print the status of the motors to the app
        aFuture.set_result(statusChanger)

    future = aio.Future()
    aio.ensure_future(getStatus(future))
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
    return future.result()
```

However, this doesn't work, as when I do `app.registerEvent(motorStatusMonitor(event_loop, app, Messenger))` it just hangs forever.

How should I actually be going about implementing async here?

Full code for everything is at [Github](https://github.com/HARDWAREdotASTRO/ROBh.aTnetwork/tree/testing).

Comment: How would you expect others to help if there's no actual code showing what you're doing.

Comment: I accidentally hit submit before asking the question, it was a mistake on my part.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve actually? Because the closure is not a problem. At the very least, you could rework your code to not use a closure but use a global `app` instead. I'm not saying closure isn't the right approach (even if it's not very popular in Python) I am saying that you might be hiting the XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Try to expand on what you are trying to achieve please.

Comment: This function is used in an event registration call, which then uses the closure as a callback function for a GUI to update the status pane of the application. The intent was to use the doubly-layered closures to create a new update function every time the `motorStatusMonitor` function was called.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Is waiting the for the future to complete which it never does.

Also you must not call `future.result()` but instead something like `await future` which will return the result.

Comment: So at the end of my function, in which i need to return the closure, I just do `return await future`, and get rid of the call to `loop.run_until_complete`?

Comment: Also, I don't think I can use `await` here, since I'm not creating a coro, this function specifically needs to be synchronous.